# Integral representation of Legendre function of the second kind

Tags: calculus, reference-request, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Does an analog of the following formula
$$
P_{\nu}\left(z_1 z_2 - \sqrt{z_1^2-1}\sqrt{z_2^2-1}\cos\psi\right) = {1\over 2\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} {\left( z_1 + \sqrt{z_1^2-1}\cos(x-\psi) \right)^{\nu} \over \left( z_2 + \sqrt{z_2^2-1}\cos(x) \right)^{\nu+1}} \, dx
$$
exist for the function $Q_{\nu}\left(z_1 z_2 - \sqrt{z_1^2-1}\sqrt{z_2^2-1}\cos\psi\right)$? I've searched in every reference I can remember but I can't find anything. A result with $\psi =0$ would be enough as well. Thanks!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
Q_n(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d \phi } {(z+ \sqrt{z^2-1} \cosh \phi )^{n+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm aware of that formula but is there another one where the $z_1$ and $z_2$ are separated?